# undefined method `border_lines=' for #<Prawn::Table::Cell::Text:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm having error for the prawn version 0.12.0:

```
undefined method `border_lines=' for #<Prawn::Table::Cell::Text:0x007fe9454aaa70>
```

Code:

```
data = [
    ["ship date", "#{order.shipping_date}"],
    ["order #", "#{order.order_number}"]
       ]
table(data, :cell_style => 
             {:border_lines => [:dotted, :dotted,:dotted,:dotted]}
      )
```

Referred to the [manual](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf).
[image]

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have a zero-width space in `border_lines`. Have you tried other `property => value` pairs there to see if anything is accepted?

Comment: For example this one worked: table(data, :cell_style => {:background_color => "FFFFCC"})

Comment: I've searched the whole distribution of prawn-0.12.0 for keyword `border_lines` and found nothing.

Comment: It seems it's deprecated...

Comment: It's still showing in the latest version on github.  See https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/search?q=border_lines&ref=cmdform.  What version are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 0.12.0. In the link you've provided I couldn't find the version information. I've also posted this issue on the prawn's google group but haven't received an answer.

Comment: now available version 1.0.0.rc2, with support of border_lines option.